# How to get Windows version 32 or 64bit in Visual Basic 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

What command in visual basic 2010 can get Windows information, specifically if Windows is 32bit or 64bit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.is64bitoperatingsystem.aspx

You will find other useful information in the Environment class.